# Grails Application running in server is very slow

Tags: performance, grails, grails-2.0

I have Grails application running in [Rackspace](http://rackspace.com) .

I am using following version of softwares.

1. Grails 2.0.4
2. jdk1.6.0_22

running on `tomcat 6 under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) 1024 MB RAM`

My application uses following plugins

```
audit-logging       0.5.4
ckeditor            3.6.3.0
cloud-foundry       1.2.1
cloud-support       1.0.11
hibernate           2.0.4
jquery              1.7.1
mail                1.0
resources           1.1.6
spring-security-core1.2.7.3
tomcat              2.0.4
webxml              1.4.1
```

Pages which has server interaction takes too much time. 
I find my application is very slow . GSP pages takes 3 seconds to 40 seconds to load .

How to fix the performance issue...?

Comment: 3+ seconds just for HTML or including all resources(css/js/images)?

Comment: 3 seconds for plain html pages.. takes 10+ seconds to load resourses

Comment: Weird, I have the same setup on my VPS and my Grails app is running fast. Try deploying a simple Grails apps to see the performance.